# Magento admin form validation doesn't working?

Tags: magento-1.9, adminform, form-validation

I have a custom grid in Admin panel. When you want to edit entries to the grid it will load a form. The required field validations of this form are not working. I have define the fields as below.

```
$fieldset->addField('discount', 'text', array(
                'label'    => $helper->__('Discount Amount (%)'),
                'required' => true,
                'class'    => 'required-entry',
                'name'     => 'discount',
                'index'    => 'discount',
        ));
```

Adding below two attributes not working. It saves even if the fields are empty.

```
'required' => true,
'class'    => 'required-entry',
```

Am I missing something else here?

Comment: Using the class "required-entry" should be sufficient to get the client side validation working. Do you see any JS errors?

Comment: there's no any JS errors. It just doesn't validate

Answer (score 3):

The form should be instantiated as a `Varien_Form` for validation to kick in. Find the ID of the form you are missing validation on, and add a little piece of Javascript to instantiate it as a `Varien_Form`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //< ![CDATA[
        var myForm = new varienForm('myFormId');
    //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: In the backend, the "V" here has to be lowercase: `var myForm = new varienForm('myFormId');`. See also: https://alanstorm.com/magento-custom-form-validation/, right at the bottom.